Monotone functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$
I am looking for references on the following topic.
It is a known fact that, every measurable function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ monotone can be seen as the sum $f = f_c + f_j$ where $f_c$ is a monotone continous function and $f_j$ is a jump function.  My question is whether this result has an analogue for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ , where a function is monotonic if $x\leq y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$ where we say that $x= (x_1,...,x_n) \leq (y_1,...,y_n)$ if and only if $x_i \leq y_i$.  Is there any analogous decomposition? I think that such a characterization is not as simple as in the case $n=1$.
What I really need is to find such a characterization for functions $f:[0,1]^n \to \mathbb{R}$.
Any kind of reference would be appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

In that case, $f(0,1/\sqrt{2}) =1$ and $f(0,1)=0$ but $(0,1/\sqrt{2}) \leq (0,1)$ so monotonicity doesn't holds.
